# React Native Footer Screen

Tags: react-native

I would like to know how I can change the colors of this screen "footer" in React Native, thank you for your help.

I tried using the statusBar component but so far without success, Or is this an Android API issue?

[image: img device simulator]

Answer (score 0):

I think u have to use SafeAreaView.